# How to make S3-method for "format" for objects with class including AsIs

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am struggling with S3 methods and class attributes for a class of "personal identification numbers" (pin). 
I have this object:

```
> pin <- structure(c("870407-9311", "560203-1234"), 
+                 class = c("pin", "character"))
```

Sometimes I want to combine this `pin` with additional data in a data.frame. Then I might get some problems with R's recycling rules, for example:

```
> data.frame(a = 1:4, pin, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Error in data.frame(a = 1:4, pin, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 2
```

One way is to skip `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` (and defactorise afterwards) such as:

```
> x <- data.frame(a = 1:4, pin)
> isfac    <- sapply(x, is.factor)
> x[isfac] <- lapply(x[isfac], as.character)
```

The problem with this solution is that it is a little bit tricky and it doesn't really feel natural.

Another way then is to use the `I` function such as:

```
 > y <- data.frame(a = 1:4, I(pin), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

That is quite al right but:

```
> class(y$pin)
[1] "AsIs"      "pin"       "character"
```

The extra class `AsIs` is OK in most cases but not when I want to define my own `format.pin` method, since the `format.AsIs` method will be found first and since it (in opposite to the other `xxx.AsIs` methods) doesn't use `NextMethod` internally.
I might be able to override the `format` function all together by:

```
format <- function(x, ...) {
  if (is.pin(x)) format.pin(x, ...)
  else base::format(x, ...)
}
```

But then, when using Roxygen2, my `format.pin` method is no longer recognized as an S3-method but as a stand alone function, hence, `export(format.pin)` and not `S3method(print,pin)` is written to the `NAMESPACE` file.

I could obviously just define a stand alone `pin_format` function (not a method) or trying to (against the recommendation) edit `NAMESPACE` by hand but I am hoping there is another (better and more natural) way to solve this!

Comment: I think you’ve found a bug here — `format.AsIs` *should* use `NextMethod`. Can you maybe override `format.AsIs` instead of `format` to fix this?

Comment: Thansk for the advice but unfortunately I don't think it's possible, since the base package still have its own method in its namespace/search path and will use `base::format.AsIs` and not `mypackage::format.AsIs`.

Comment: For now, I refine the `format` generic with: `format <- function(x, ...) {
  if (is.pin(x)) format.pin(x, ...) else UseMethod("format")}`